# Calling a web service on a remote server with jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services

I have been stuck on this issue for hours now, unable to find a valid answer, perhaps because of my lack of knowledge/experience with such things.

I am aware that I cannot load a web service on a remote server with XMLHttpRequest due to Same-Origin restriction, but apparently this can be done with jsonp data type and providing a callback function but I really can't figure out how to make it work.

The remote server would be mine, so I don't really care about the possiblity that the remote server can send back any malicious javascript code.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me to get some working code with the web service at http://www.antoinecloutier.com/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld

I have created a test page on my server and the web services works fine --> http://antoinecloutier.com/test.html

Now, I need to be able to access that web service from a different server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `Cross Domain AJAX Calls using jquery` by enabling CORS

For eg:

```
 jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://crossdomainurl',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",           
        success: function (data) {                
            WriteResponse(data);
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
        }
  });
```

To Make Sure Cross Domain Work Properly you will have to add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header to the web service response.

In a .NET WCF service, you can add this to the global.asax of your service as follows,

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
}
```

In PHP you can modify the response as follows,

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

`Note:`

Sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header allows basic cross-origin access, but calling ASP.NET services like ASMX ScriptServices, ASPX page methods, and WCF services with AspNetCompatibilityRequirements enabled requires your site to respond with one additional CORS header: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

You can configure the same in `web.config` as follows,

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/7jlh6y1vqa1cjv8bjec0g

Can you help me get a working example with this code please?

Comment: I have added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my Application_BeginRequest as mentionned, but I am still getting the following error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.antoinecloutier.com/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld. The request was redirected to 'http://antoinecloutier.com/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Here is the code: http://pastie.org/private/nvtldi38lto21p3vnswglq.
I am using an ASMX service rather than WCF, is that a problem?

Comment: @newblt123 some more info for you. see the updated answer and also look for the `content type` added in ajax call.

Comment: Thank you. Might wanna remove the Application_BeginRequest part, as only the part in the web.config is needed (if you have both, you will have an error saying you need only one definition).

Comment: just a note header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ') is very dangerous because it allows any domain.