# CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, cors

I am getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:62574/ServiceClass.asmx?op=loadMarkersViaWebService. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:15540' is therefore not allowed access.
```

so I added the following in the Web.Config, however error still persists:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:15540/"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: I see a port mismatch?

Comment: @Niels no, Application is using 15540, while web service is using 62574

Comment: Have a look at my accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127442/calling-a-web-service-on-a-remote-server-with-jquery/22128497#22128497

Comment: @rikket , found a solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try Using This..

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
 </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```